# Unsupported PCL Profile in Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios, portable-class-library

I am working with the GoPro camera and trying to run a library made by r1pper. The [project](https://github.com/r1pper/GoPro.Hero) is described as

> A lightweight c# library to access and control GoPro HERO Action cameras
> It has a functional media browser based on Ambarella and GoPro App, it has also the full control of the camera, and live preview.

I am having trouble when trying to compile on the Xamarin IDE:

> /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/3.10.0/lib/mono/4.5/Microsoft.Common.targets: Error:
>
> Unsupported PCL Profile '.NETPortable,Version=v4.0,Profile=Profile96'. (GoPro.Hero)

I have looked at a couple of forums and blogs that mention there is no fix for this bug:

- http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/164/pcl-build-problems
- http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/6334/problem-with-pcl-support-after-update

Is there really no workaround to this bug? Or am I misunderstanding something?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like Profile 96 is not available in Mono.

I would change the Portable Class Library (PCL) project so it targets a different profile that is available on Mono. I would pick Profile 78 or Profile 259 since these are the ones generally recommended by Xamarin. You can do this in the Project Options under Build - General.

You may need to reinstall/retarget the NuGet packages after changing the project's PCL profile. If you are using a recent version of Xamarin Studio then it should tell you if this is the case in the Package Console window.

Answer (score 2):

If I'm not mistaken you didn't install Visual Studio 2012/2013 (which Automatically configure MSBuild for PCL usage), in this case you should install and configure PCL on your system manually (it is only needed for development, not for distribution)

Here are the steps based on this [Guide](http://xamarinandroid.blogspot.nl/2014/06/portable-class-librarypcl-setup-for.html)

**1- Install [.NET Framework 4.5.1](http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=40779)**

**2- Install [Mono MDK](http://download.mono-project.com/archive/3.2.3/windows-installer/mono-3.2.3-gtksharp-2.12.11-win32-0.exe)**

**3- Install [PCL Library Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/b0e0b5e9-e138-410b-ad10-00cb3caf4981/)** : it will install MSBuild tools and Profile96

**4-(Optional) [Install PCL Reference Assemblies](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40727)** for newer PCL profiles

after installation copy 4.6 PCL assemblies from

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft .NET Portable Library Reference Assemblies 4.6\PortableReferenceAssemblies.zip`

to

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETPortable`

**5-Reinstall Xamarin Suite**